# environment variable clientname scope on terminal server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, terminal-server, environment-variables, batch

I have a script that needs the CLIENTNAME environment variable, it runs on a terminal server.
I have a batch file for testing that contains:
**set CLIENTNAME; pause**

**If I RDP as an admin:**
If I open a command prompt, run the script, it shows the clientname.
If I double click on the script, the CLIENTNAME variable does not exist.

**If I Login from igel/wyse terminal:**
If I double click on the same script, the it shows the clientname.

Other details: 2008R2, Xenapp 6.5, testing as a domain admin.

What's happening with the environment variable CLIENTNAME?
Why doesn't it exist when I double click on the batch file if I am RDPd to the server but does exist if a command prompt is already open?
All the other environment variables seem to be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **SYMPTOMS** When connecting remotely with Remote Desktop Connection, the environment variables `CLIENTNAME` and `SESSIONNAME` are added to each
>   process that is started.
>
> If you set the Folder Option "Launch folder windows in a separate
>   process" and later launch an application from an additional Explorer
>   window, the application will not see these additional environment
>   variables.
>
> **CAUSE** The additional Explorer window is not a child window of the parent Explorer.exe process, but launched from the system process.
>   Therefore it does not inherit the environment from the Explorer main
>   window.
>
> **RESOLUTION**  If your application relies on these variables, remove the folder option "Launch folder windows in a separate process".

[image: Clientname and Sessionname enviroment variable may be missing]

Quotation: [Clientname and Sessionname enviroment variable may be missing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2509192).

Comment: Thanks JosefZ! That was exactly the cause. It would also explain why the variables were available in the Powershell ISE but not if I launched the script with a batch file.